# How to check/uncheck a checkbox based on the state check/uncheck of another checkbox

Tags: jquery

Guys im trying to check/uncheck a checkbox based on the state check/uncheck of another checkbox. And im trying to build a Jquery script to do that for every checkbox here.

Basically i want to set to checked  the status of "lists_1" whenever id="CustomFields[12_1]_la1" is checked. And also set the status of to unchecked whenever is id="CustomFields[12_1]_la1".

And the same for the rest: so the correlations are:
CustomFields[12_1]_la1 ---> lists_1
CustomFields[12_1]_la2 ---> lista_2
and on and on...

NOTE: i CANT change the name of the ids.

```
<td><span class="required">*</span>&nbsp;
concesionarias:</td>
    <td><label for="CustomFields[12_1]_la1"><input type="checkbox"     id="CustomFields[12_1]_la1" name="CustomFields[12][]" value="la1">la1</label><br/><label     for="CustomFields[12_1]_la2"><input type="checkbox" id="CustomFields[12_1]_la2"     name="CustomFields[12][]" value="la2">la2</label><br/><label for="CustomFields[12_1]_la3">    <input type="checkbox" id="CustomFields[12_1]_la3" name="CustomFields[12][]"     value="la3">la3</label><br/><label for="CustomFields[12_1]_la4"><input type="checkbox"     id="CustomFields[12_1]_la4" name="CustomFields[12][]" value="la4">la4</label><br/></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact Lists:</td>
    <td><label for="lists_1"><input type="checkbox" id="lists_1" name="lists[]"     value="1" />&nbsp;ddsd</label></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><label for="lists_2"><input type="checkbox" id="lists_2" name="lists[]"     value="2" />&nbsp;laconce1</label></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><label for="lists_3"><input type="checkbox" id="lists_3" name="lists[]"     value="3" />&nbsp;laconce2</label></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><label for="lists_4"><input type="checkbox" id="lists_4" name="lists[]"     value="4" />&nbsp;laconce3</label></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ESTADO:</td>
    <td><select name="CustomFields[13]" id="CustomFields_13_1"><option value="">--      Please choose an option --</option><option value="Contacto">Contacto</option><option     value="Oportunidad">Oportunidad</option><option value="Vendido">Vendido</option></select>    </td>
</tr><input type="hidden" name="format" value="h" />
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
                <br/>
            </td>
```

This is the script ive tried and it doesnt work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#CustomFields[12_1]_la1").click(function() {
               if ($("CustomFields[12_1]_la1").attr("checked") == true) {
                $("lists_1").attr('checked', true);
                } else if ($("CustomFields[12_1]_la1").attr("checked") == false) {
                 $("lists_1").attr('checked', false);
                }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Can sombody suggest a new working one for what im trying to accomplish? Thanks for all

Comment: I see that you can not change the id values on the elements but can add class names on these elements?  This would greatly simplify your target element selection.  Also onChange is your friend here.  If you bind to onClick, you are really working with the side effect of the click event which is a change in the value.  If some other code changes the checked values directly, your click backed updating will break.  Just FYI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old ----------

Demo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //bind event to checkbox
  $("input[type='checkbox']").bind('click', function(){

    var $t = $(this); 

    // check if element is checked
    if($t.val() == 'la1' && $t.is(':checked')) {
      $("#lists_1").attr('checked', true);
    }
    else {
      $("#lists_1").attr('checked', false);
    }
  });
});
```

New -------

Demo can be found **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/F7nBL/6/)**

CHANGE -- This will handle multiple checkbox to list relationships dynamically. (This was assumed from your markup. So CustomFields[12_1]_la1 -> list_1 and CustomFields[12_1]_la2 -> list_2 will map to each like so.)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //bind event to checkbox
  $("input[type='checkbox']").bind('click', function(){
    var $t = $(this),
        val = $t.val(),
        key = val.charAt(val.length-1);

    // check if element is checked
    if($t.val() == 'la'+key && $t.is(':checked')) {
      $("#lists_"+key).attr('checked', true);
    }
    else if($t.val() == 'la'+key){
      $("#lists_"+key).attr('checked', false);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Kieran thanks for ur solution BUUT the problem is unfortunately i CANT change the name of the "ids", they need to remain as i said. WHY? Its becasue this is part of a form taht was exported from an app, so this form generates leads/contacts tht get inserted into this particular contact management script. Thats why i cant change IDS. Do you think i could still accomplish my goals without touching the ids?

Comment: This may not be ideal for performance or the cleanest approach but it will make it so you can still control the checkbox elements by their values. Its a work around. You could also change the bind to delegate() if you wanted to but this should work.

Comment: Uhm.. your answer works, but is not too clean or efficient. Especially if there are more than one checkboxes which need to toggle others (as the OP stated in his question).

Comment: IS ur solution better or worse than what Veger proposed?

Comment: Veger i tested this with the 4 checkboxes and it seems to be working

Comment: i keep adding the if, else statements for the rest of the checkboxes and it works but maybe there could be another problem taht i dont see?

Comment: Kieran, you changed the code. Is this new modification better than the previous (working) one=?

Comment: The new change will handle all checkbox elements and the mapping to the respective list. Veger's approach was directly to the element and mine was all checkbox elements on the page, which is obviously slower if you're dealing with tons of objects on a page. However, if the logic repeats itself for each checkbox then my approach would be correct since you'll end up writing more code trying to handle the conditionals on each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling an attribute using

```
$("lists_1").attr('checked', false);
```

does not work, but you need to use

```
$("lists_1").removeAttr('checked');
```

Browsers only check if the attribute 'checked' is present, they do not look to its value. Probably because all the different uses: checked, checked="checked", checked="true", etc. Therefore you need to remove the checked attribute *completely* using the [removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) method.

**Update**
A second problem are the missing `#` in front of the `lists_1` parts.

And there is a third problem: you are using special characters in your ids. You need to escape these special cacharters with `\\` according to the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#CustomFields\\[12_1\\]_la1').click(function() {
    var myChecked = $(this).attr("checked");
    if (myChecked == true) 
      $("#lists_1").attr('checked', true);
    else
      $("#lists_1").removeAttr('checked');
  });
});
```

A live demo can be found [here](http://jsbin.com/ubiki3/edit). (I also took the liberty to clean the rest of your JavaScript code as well.)

Comment: can you please suggest a code for the first example? (first checkbox in the first set and first checkbox in the other set) so then i can build from there

Comment: I did: replace your line (first code block in my answer) with the new line (second code block in my answer).

Comment: It doesnt work. Your suggestion is correct but my script doesnt work, can u take a look if u can?

Comment: Correct, there was a second and a third problem!

Comment: IS ur answer better in some way than the solution proposed by Kieran? i would like to understand if there are advantages to learn, thanks for ur solution as well

Comment: In my answer jQuery is used as it was intended, since it adds the click-handler directly to the element. Instead of working around it by binding a click-handler to *all* input elements and manually checking. With the only reason beging the special charcters `[` and `]` of the id which can be escaped easily with `\\\`. Furthermore is it assumed good practice to use `removeAttr()` to disable an attribute of an element, since this approach always works.

Comment: @Veger +1 - One way that it was intended ;)  It would be perfectly understandable to write the element checking logic in a handler that was supposed to be bound on a single parent element and catch events that had bubbled up.

Answer (score 0):

you're not referencing the checkboxes properly, need to use class or ID

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#CustomFields[12_1]_la1").click(function() {

                    $("#lists_1").attr('checked', $(this).attr("checked"));
                    $("#lists_2").attr('checked', $(this).attr("checked"));
                    $("#lists_3").attr('checked', $(this).attr("checked"));
                   $("#lists_4").attr('checked', $(this).attr("checked"));

            });
        });
    </script>
```

though if you could give them a common class you could:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#CustomFields[12_1]_la1").click(function() {

                    $(".lists_all").attr('checked', $(this).attr("checked"));

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try binding to the change event instead of to the click event.  This way you are updating the related checkboxes based on the value of the changed element after the click.

```
function change_handler(e) {
    var $t = $(e.target),
        t_is_checked = $t.is(':checked'),
        list_number = $t.attr('id').split('_').reverse()[0].splice(2),
        related_item_id = "#list_" + list_number,
        related_item = $(related_item_id);
    related_item.attr('checked', t_is_checked ? '' : 'checked');
}

// bind to all your target input fields (maybe give them a class for easy selection)
// (just binding one for this example)

$("#CustomFields[12_1]_la1")
    //.unbind('change') // really handy if you are testing the code via console
    .bind('change', change_handler)
    .change(); // trigger a bogus change event to setup the initial checkbox state
```